# Should I use a lambda or functor for a comparison function?

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring

I am refactoring a C++03 project to C++11.

I have a class which has a functor defined within it for sorting:

```
class Widget
{
public:

  class SortByRules
  {
  public:
    bool operator()(const Widget &lhs, const Widget &rhs) const;
  }
}
```

This functor is used in various places throughout my project. An example usage:

```
std::vector<Widget> widgets;

// ...

std::sort(widgets.begin(), widgets.end(), Widget::SortByRules());
```

As far as I understand, lambdas should be prefered to functors in C++11. But I'm not sure if I should just stick with a functor in this case because I want to call it in multiple other classes throughout my project.

I was thinking of refactoring to something like the following:

```
// .h
class Widget
{
public:
 Widget();
 std::function<bool(Widget&, Widget&)> SortByRules;
};

// .cpp
Widget::Widget() :
SortByRules([](Widget& lhs, Widget& rhs) { /* ... */ }
{
}
```

Are both of these implementations essentially the same? Should I prefer one over the other, and if so, why?

Comment: Another option is to have the lambda returned by a function: `auto byRuleSorting() { return [](const Widget& lhs, const Widget& rhs) { ... }; }`.

Comment: remember that lambda expressions create nameless functors...

Comment: If you already have code that works, don't just throw it away. Just because there are new features that could do what you're already doing doesn't make your code obsolete. If it makes sense to keep the old code then keep it.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree for the most part, but I think refactoring is a valuable tool for learning. At least it has been for me. That's why I'm doing this.

Comment: Personnaly, I use lambda for short and simple expression. If I have to use the same lambda in 2 different place, or it's a non-trivial function I usually use a functor or a `std::function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice for the choice between lambda and a names functor is: If you need to refer to the name of the functor type, then use a named functor, otherwise you can use a lambda (if you so prefer).

A case where the type name is needed is indeed when storing the functor as a member variable. So, a named functor would be preferable in that case. Using a function wrapper for this case would introduce unnecessary runtime overhead.

There are also cases where you may need to refer to types of deduced parameters where lambda isn't usable until c++20.

You can make a lambda easily reusable by returning it from a function.

Comment: Is there any advantage of returning a lambda from a function instead of simply implementing the body of the lambda in the function?

Comment: @BasinhetVeld they do different things. Implementing the lambda in the function means that body is executed when the function is. But returning a lambda gives you a callable that can be called later. Of course, the function could be made callable later with a function pointer. But compilers aren't as good at optimising across a function pointer as they are at optimising function objects. Another typical pattern is to capture arguments passed to the function inside the lambda, which is not possible with a function pointer.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Lambdas are basically just syntactic sugar for functors. Their main advantage is their dense syntax and that you can define them inline without the need to give them a name.

> This functor is used in various places throughout my project.

If you want to name the type and use it in different places, then using a lambda has no great advantage over using your functor class.